# Jammit gem is expanding the path of font files

Tags: jammit

After running the jammit -c assets.yml -o assets command, Jammit goes through all of my CSS files and changes them around before concatenating everything. It, for some reason, expands the URL() path for all of my @font-face url paths to the absolute path of the file located on my computer. Is there any way to get this to say as an absolute path within the public directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem. Turns out that the font files were not located in the public directory so jammit was making sure that the path exists outside of that.